# Calendar showing wrong date and time

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-date

```
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();          
        Toast.makeText(alarm.this, " "+c.DAY_OF_MONTH+ " " +c.MONTH+ " " +c.YEAR ,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

this code is showing 05-02-01 as the date, instead of todays date (25-08-2011)
Can anybody tell me what is happening?

regards
sandeep

Comment: can you try c.get(Calendar.YEAR) , c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)?

Comment: @Ben Almost ;-) According to Calendar: `public static final int SEPTEMBER = 8;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `get` method to get the actual field values:

```
c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) ...
```

The value `DAY_OF_MONTH` is actually a constant referencing the fields of the calendar object.

Answer (score 0):

and, according to what Howard says in comment, you must add 1 to get the exact value for the month since it's coded between 0 and 11 :

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
Toast.makeText(alarm.this, String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)).show();
```

Comment: thanks Darkendorf. my problem was because, i was using c.DAY_OF_MONTH, instead of c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

Comment: yeah i know, i was just adding this piece of information for those like me who ended on this thread searching also for month ^^